# Android / Eclipse - Graphical Layout (XML) not updating when I make changes to AVD

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-virtual-device

In Eclipse, I have created an AVD for a Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini.

When I look at a screen layout in the `Graphical Layout` tab, the items aren't laid out as I know they are on a real device, so (resorting to trial and error) I go back into the `AVD Manager` and change some of the layout properties...

I then go back to the `Graphical Layout` for my screen to view the changes, but nothing has changed.

I change the orientation from vertical to horizontal to vertical, but the layout is still the same as it was before I changed the AVD.

I select a different AVD in the dropdown (located at the top of the `Graphical Layout` window), then come back to my AVD, but it still hasn't changed.

I've also tried closing and re-opening the XML file - but to no avail.

**The only way I can get the `Graphical Layout` to update is to restart Eclipse!...
Is there an easier way?! :-/**

Comment: Are you using different layout for different resolution?

Comment: Restart eclipse and emulator then clean your project. It might be works for you

Comment: Amsheer, I am currently using the same layout for each resolution, but when I change the screen width in the AVD, it does not update on the UI.

Comment: Vipul, restarting Eclipse does work, but I don't want to do this each time I change the AVD settings as, this way, it could take hours until I get the setting right.

Comment: Clean & Build project doesn't do it, either.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I resolved it by running the app in the emulator: the layout will update after you make any changes.

This is not the correct method because you have to run the app in the emulator every time you make a change.

I'm interested if you guys have any other way.